# Concatenate strings, convert to ushort, compare against ushort

Tags: c#, string, uint16, ushort

So I have some constants:

```
const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_NT4 = 0x0400;
const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K = 0x0500;
....
```

And then I have a major version number, minor version number, and service pack number, that, when you concatenate those together, it's the same as the number above - except 2 of them are `int` and one is a `string`.  I can get them all into a string like this:

```
string version = majorVersion.ToString() + minorVersion.ToString() + sp;
```

For Windows 2000, this would look like `"500"`.  It "matches" the ushort, just without the `0x0`.

What I'd like to do is hand off `version` to a function, as a `ushort` that returns the correct OS:

```
private static string WindowsVersion(ushort uniNum)
{
    switch (uniNum)
    {
        case _WIN32_WINNT_NT4:
            return "Windows NT 4.0";
        case _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K:
            return "Windows 2000";
        ....
        default:
            return "Unknown OS version.";
    }
 }
```

The problem is, even if I do:

```
ushort uniNum = Convert.ToUInt16(version);
```

And say it sends it in as `500`, the constant is `0x0500`, so it never finds the OS and returns `Unknown OS version`, instead.  When I debug and hover over `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K`, it's actually `1280` in decimal format. 
 `_WIN32_WINNT_NT4` is showing as `1024`, so `"400"` would never match it.

And if I include the "0x0":

```
ushort uniNum = Convert.ToUInt16("0x0" + version);
```

It gives me an error that the input is in the incorrect format.

I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't find anything anywhere that's been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the constants and they are hexadecimal. If you are getting `400` and `500` they are also hexadecimal, so replace:

```
ushort uniNum = Convert.ToUInt16(version);
```

with:

```
ushort uniNum = Convert.ToUInt16(version, 16);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I needed.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Your constant declaration's value is a hexadecimal literal expression:

```
const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_NT4 = 0x0400;
```

Where `0x0400` is equivalent to hex `400`, decimal `1024`. So basically, you're not comparing to 400 but to 1024.

Change your constant to be 400 if you'd like to compare against 400:

```
const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_NT4 = 400;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is possible as 1) then it's not a `ushort` anymore - might as well call them all `int`, 2) I don't have control over what comes back from the Microsoft function as to how it defines itself.

Comment: Also, if it were hex 400, the decimal would be 190, not 1024.  I don't know how Visual Studio is getting 1024 for `0x0400`.